# ns1: C# deserialization issue

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

Below is the test code used to get the ns1: issue, I always get a object with nothing in it.

if I remove the two `[XmlType]` and `[XmlRoot]` it errors.

I am sure some one already should have faced the problem not getting the right term to search probably,

hope fully its a simple thing.

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://itaintworking.com/test/")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://itaintworking.com/test/", IsNullable = false)]
public class Clients
{
    public string clientName { get; set; }
    public addressDetails addressDetails { get; set; }
}

public class addressDetails
{
    public int addressId { get; set; }
}

[Test(Description = "Serialization Exception")]
public void CheckDeserializer()
{
    var strXml =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><ns1:Clients xmlns:ns1=\"http://itaintworking.com/test/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" ><clientName>hello</clientName><addressDetails><addressId>98989</addressId></addressDetails></ns1:Clients>";
    var x = XmlSerializer<Clients>.Deserialize(strXml);
    Assert.IsNotNull(x);
}
```

I am using some code which uses generics, there is another method defaulting to UTF8 encoding, and a null for the xmlReaderSetting.

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserializes a XML string into an object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xml">The XML string to deserialize</param>
/// <param name="encoding">The encoding</param>
/// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings"/></param>
/// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
public static T Deserialize(string xml, Encoding encoding, XmlReaderSettings settings)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        throw new ArgumentException("XML cannot be null or empty", "xml");

    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(xml)))
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream, settings))
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly how you would want this to be fixed.

As it currently stands in the XML, the `clientName` and `addressDetails` elements within the `Clients` element are not in the same namespace. So, one fix is:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://itaintworking.com/test/")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://itaintworking.com/test/", IsNullable = false)]
public class Clients
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace="")]
    public string clientName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public addressDetails addressDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Another fix might be to change the namespaces in the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:Clients xmlns:ns1="http://itaintworking.com/test/"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <ns1:clientName>hello</ns1:clientName>
   <ns1:addressDetails>
       <ns1:addressId>98989</ns1:addressId>
   </ns1:addressDetails>
 </ns1:Clients>
```

Comment: You are awesome, Damien, all I needed was XmlElement(Namespace="") that solves the problem